# Preventing recipient from seeing my default mail when sending from a different account than the default in Gmail

Tags: gmail

When sending mail from a different account (say beta@gmail.com) than my default in Gmail (say alpha@gmail.com), when someone reply to me I can see that my alpha@gmail.com is mentioned in the conversation along with beta@gmail.com.

For example:

> From: alpha@gmail.com on behalf of beta@gmail.com

Also, I tried to send myself mail to gamma@gmail.com from beta@gmail.com (through alpha account) and when clicking the `show original` in the message I can see my alpha@gmail.com there.

When I send mails from beta@gmail.com I don't want the recipient to know about alpha@gmail.com. Is there any way to prevent that from happening other than logging out from alpha and logging in to beta?

Answer (score 0):

### Remove "Treat as an Alias" setting

Go into settings -> accounts tab
Find the affected email address and click "edit info"
Uncheck "Treat as an alias"
Depending on the email address you are using, you may now need to configure it to send through gmail.

**Source:** https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338?ctx=gmail&hl=en&authuser=0&rd=1